# Travelling out of the country

Tags: riddle, real

**Where did Kate go?**

Below is a fictitious conversation:

```
John: How was your trip?   
Kate: It was great! I got a lot done.  
John: Fully recovered?  
Kate: I still have calluses on my feet.  
John: Really? I wouldn't have thought you'd have done any walking.  
Kate: No, they're on the top of my feet.
```

It's been about an hour, so here's a couple hints:

Medium Hint:

> Kate is a real person.  Several of her colleagues have mentioned the issue of of calluses on the top of their feet (I selected Kate because she has not; I wanted this puzzle to be somewhat Google-resistant).

Very strong hint:

> The conversation above references a past trip.  Kate just went on another trip to the same place.

Comment: Are you sure that [real] applies? That means this is a situation you encountered in real life. Also, it seems that [enigmatic-puzzle] should be used here, since there isn't any clear method of solving. Unless you mean for it to be a [riddle]?

Comment: @bobble: (Rot13 since this reply gives a very weak hint): V qvfnterr gung ravtzngvp-chmmyr vf nccebcevngr; V srry yvxr zl hfr bs gur `erny` gnt znxrf vg pyrne gung fbyiref zhfg zngpu guvf fgbel gb n erny yvsr curabzran.  Naq lrf, V qb pbafvqre gur `erny` gnt gb or nccebcevngr urer.

Comment: @bobbe: I'm honestly not sure whether riddle is appropriate.  I feel like the riddle tag implies an element of lateral thinking that doesn't really apply, here.  That said, lateral thinking is it's own tag, so I'll throw in the riddle tag; it's not an awful fit.

Comment: We are an international community; many members will have not had a chance to see your puzzle. For this reason it's standard practice to wait at least a day before any major hint drop. 2 large ones right off the bat seems like too much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think

> The destination was the International Space Station. Kate could be NASA Astronaut Kate Rubins who is currently on the International Space Station and has been up there before.

Because

> other astronauts have mentioned calluses on the top of their toes from hanging on to things to keep from floating away.

Also

> I'm sure she got a lot done and didn't do a lot of walking in zero-g

Comment: Avpryl qbar. Haorxabjafg gb zr jura V nfxrq guvf dhrfgvba, fur neevirq ng gur VFF lrfgreqnl.  Gung vf yvxryl jul lbhghor fgnegrq chfuvat nfgebanhg ivqrbf gb zr, juvpu vf ubj V yrnearq nobhg guvf vffhr.

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

> Kate went mountain climbing. Concrete finishers get calluses on top of their feet when do finishing with hand tools.

Comment: An excellent attempt, though not quite what I was looking for.  A few places where this doesn't quite fit: 1) Mountain climbers will often have calluses on the bottom of their feet.  2) Mountain climbing typically involves plenty of walking.